# Grunt Nodemon failing while initializing

Tags: javascript, grunt-nodemon, grun

I am trying to start grunt when ever there is a js change and have following code:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        nodemon: {
            all: {
                script: "server.js",
                options: {
                    watchedExtensions:['js']
                }
            }
        },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['nodemon']);

};
```

But getting following error:
Line 11, Char 5 , expected identifier,string or number.

Line 11 , char 5 is  }, (curly braces)

My `Server.js` looks like following .

```
var http = require("http")


var controllers = require("./controllers");

var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "vash");

//Set the public static resource folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

//Map the routes
controllers.init(app);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(5465);
```

Comment: looks strange can you get rid of the trailing comma ","

Comment: @MaheshSapkal, Tried that , still not working

Comment: How does your server.js looks like ?

Comment: @MaheshSapkal. Updated Server.js

Comment: That error is because of the trailing comma on line 10

Comment: Replicated the whole setup on my machine and it's working fine. Are you using latest version of node.js and grunt-nodemon ?